# Handling query exceptions with a data type other than List

Tags: apex, controller

So normally I do something like this:

```
List<Account> acctsList = [SELECT Reward_Points__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:accountId];

if (acctsList.size() > 0) {
    if (acctsList[0].Reward_Points__c != null){
        acctsList[0].Reward_Points__c += 5;
    } else {
        acctsList[0].Reward_Points__c = 5;
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is something more like this:

```
Account selectedAcct = [SELECT Reward_Points__c FROM Account WHERE Id=:accountId LIMIT 1];

if (selectedAcct != null) {
    // code block
}
```

Something like the above, except that it works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what you already use, the standard approach is to query to a `List` and simply check if it is empty.

```
List<Account> candidates = [SELECT ... FROM Account WHERE ... LIMIT 1];
if (!candidates.isEmpty())
{
    Account selectedAccount = candidates[0];
    // manipulate selected record
}
```

However, if you *really* want to use a `try`/`catch` strategy, the error thrown is a `QueryException`.

```
Account selectedRecord;
try
{
    selectedRecord = [/*query*/];
}
catch (QueryException q) { }
if (selectedRecord != null)
{
    // manipulate selected record
}
```

Note that this latter approach is slower, and you should avoid exceptions when there is an obvious path to do so.